# What are some idioms that refer to taking advantage of an opportunity to the fullest?

Tags: idioms

I'm looking for idioms along the lines of "milk it"

Comment: _Carpe diem_, Latin for 'seize the day', is the classic one. BTW, it's not an idiom; it's a phrase in another language.

Comment: Also, *strike while the iron is hot*.

Comment: *Milk it for all it is worth*, as you have hinted at.

Answer (score 2):

When you are *taking advantage of an opportunity to the fullest*, you are ***making the most of*** it.

TFD(idioms):

> **[make the most of something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+the+most+of)**
>   **to use or enjoy something as much as possible**
>   We're only in Paris for a day so let's make the
>   most of it
>
> Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms Copyright © Cambridge
>   University Press 2003. Reproduced with permission.
>
> **[make the most of something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+the+most+of)**
>   **to take full advantage of something because it may not last long**
>   Make the most of the good weather because rain is forecast for
>   tomorrow.
>
> Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed. Copyright © Cambridge University
>   Press 2006. Reproduced with permission.

Answer (score -1):

How about 'take advantage of' a situation? 'Suck the life out of it'...